# What actually causes temporal isolation

Tags: genetics, evolution, gene, species-distribution, macroevolution

Temporal isolation is caused when members of the same species are available to reproduce at the same time. How is such a phenomenon even possible, is it caused by mutations which lead to a certain percent of the population to reproduce at Time A and the other at Time B?

Comment: As the question is written, it could be answered on several levels, and may benefit from clarification. Are you looking for how general reproductive isolation can arise? You ask how the phenomenon is possible, so are you looking for examples of temporal isolation? You mention mutations, so is your question specifically about the genetics of temporal isolation? Remember that temporal isolation is likely found in an extremely diverse set of organisms, so it will not be caused by just one gene or one mechanism.